# Combobox updating another Combobox Java

Tags: java, jcombobox

Trying to populate another combobox with the selection of the first. I'm not sure why this isn't working. Thoughts?

```
    DefaultComboBoxModel typeModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] 
    {"Select Type", "Food", "Drink", "Merchandise"});

    typeComboBox.setModel(typeModel);

    typeComboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            String type = String.valueOf(typeComboBox.getSelectedItem()).trim();
            DefaultComboBoxModel drinkModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Select Subtype", "Cocktail", "Bottle Beer", "Draft Beer", "Wine", "N/A"});
            DefaultComboBoxModel foodModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Select Subtype", "Entree", "Appetizer", "Dessert", "Soup", "Side", "Misc", "Special", "Salad"});
            DefaultComboBoxModel merchModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Select Subtype", "Clothing", "Misc", "Gift Card", "Glassware"});
            switch (type) {
                case "Food":
                    subtypeComboBox.setModel(foodModel);
                case "Drink":
                    subtypeComboBox.setModel(drinkModel);
                case "Merchandise":
                    subtypeComboBox.setModel(merchModel);
                default:
                    subtypeComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: First of all, what actually goes wrong?  Compile error, runtime error, the code runs but does nothing?

Comment: Runs and does nothing for the second combobox. First combo box loads the model and has the proper selections. What I'm trying to do is when an option is selected from the first combobox, the second combobox will populate with the corresponding subtype with the models created.

Comment: Have you done any debugging?  Have you verified whether the `itemStateChanged` method is running, for example?

Comment: The `break` keyword is missing in your `switch` block and it always executes the `default` clause. Consequently your second combo box looks always empty because of the empty combo box model being set.

Comment: ^ That was it. I feel so ashamed now. Thank you so much!